# Adding Image for banner

Tags: 7, media, javascript

I want to add the banner image from the Admin page. The banner is slider. The slider contains text, Read more link and Images.

These three options user have to add from the admin page. The slider appears only in the home page.

Is there any plugin or Content type is advisable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When i Google [drupal image sliders](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=drupal%20image%20sliders&aq=f&oq=drupal%20image%20sliders&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62j64.3413&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) the second result leads me to this.

#### Available modules

There are many modules that provide some sort of slideshow / rotator functionality.

- Views Slideshow Liquid Slider - A fully responsive, HTML5 jQuery content slider for both web and mobile devices.
- Content Glider - Another jQuery plugin for image slider, very easy to use.
- Flex slider - provides a client-side automatic adaptation of the slides size according to the window size (Responsive). Can work with the Views module. Poor documentation.
- jCarousel - This module allows developers and themers to make use of the jCarousel jQuery plugin. It includes a developer API that other modules can use, as well as Views integration in the 2.0 version so that you can turn any list of content or images into a carousel.
- Dynamic display block - Enables you to create and present blocks of content in a dynamic and attractive way. Uses the jQuery Cycle Plug-in.
- Views Nivo Slider - a Views style plugin using the Nivo style slider.  Drupal 6 version requires imagecache, imagefield and jquery update.
- Views Slideshow - a Views style plugin using jquery cycle. Provides an extensible API that allows other cycles, rotators, and carousels to plug into the module, so they don't need to recreate the Views functionality.
- Views Slideshow: Dynamic display block - a Views slideshow plugin which enables you to present slideshows in an attractive way.
- Views Slideshow Xtra is an enhancement module for Views Slideshow, providing the ability to create animated slideshow overlays.  This module can also help automate the creation of any Drupal 7 Views Slideshow, using the Views Slideshow Xtra Example sub-module, which creates a Slide content type, a default Slideshow View, and example Slide nodes.
- Views Slideshow: ImageFlow - offers an ImageFlow option to Views Slideshow, similar to Apple's CoverFlow.
- Slideshow Creator - adds an input format filter to allow you to add slideshow creation code to the body of a node and other text fields.
- Featured Content Slider - select nodes based on content type and create up to 3 blocks of featured content.
- Slider - create a "slider" content type with a multi-value nodereference field to create carousel-style sliders of the referenced nodes.
- Ajax Slideshow - Sequential presentation of any of the site nodes, using various effects. The slideshow is ajax-based which means the page load-time is agnostic to the amount of content included.
- Media Nivo Slider - Provides the ability to expose the content of a Media Gallery to a Nivo Slider block.
- Nivo formatter - Nivo formatter is an image field formatter that transform any image field
      to awesome Nivo Slider image gallery.
- Nivo Slider - Nivo Slider is a stand-alone solution for creating a simple slideshow for your website.